# Web Service Errors not bubbling up

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7

I created a *web service using ASP.net / C#*. I added a service reference to the *.asmx* file in my *Windows Phone 7* project (C# again). Under normal circumstances this works great.

I need to be able to handle situations when the web service is down or otherwise throws an error. When the service is unavailable, I get an error in a `Reference.cs` file (this appears to be something autogenerated when I added the Service Reference) when it tries to get the `_result` value. The inner exception of this is

```
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound.".
```

After getting the error, the app stops executing. I need to be able to catch this error so the app doesn't stop.

This is the code I call to execute my web service.

```
HighScoresWSSoapClient client = new HighScoresWSSoapClient();
  client.LoadUserByANIDCompleted += this.client_LoadUserByANIDCompleted;
  client.LoadUserByANIDAsync(this.anid);
```

I added a `try/catch` block in the `client_LoadUserByANIDCompleted` event.

In the debugger, when I it the error, execution of the app stops. If I press play, it then proceeds to enter the `try/catch` block and it does correctly go to the catch section where I can handle it...

But because it stops initially on the `_result` line, it doesn't normally get to that point. I'm at a loss why it won't bubble up to my `try/catch` without pressing play again and not sure how to make this work in a real world situation.

I hope this is enough info to go on and makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is just a strange thing the debugger does and there isn't a way around it. If you run this code outside of the debugger, it bubbles the error up to the try/catch block and you can handle it. Inside the debugger, you must press play to go through it but then you can handle it too.

Comment: The fact that the debugger catches exceptions is considered to be a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is enable WCF logging and use the Service Trace Viewer to view its output. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098515/silverlight-wcf-database-problem/2098605#2098605) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not having trouble determining what the error is (I know the problem, I unplugged my router). The error happens but the program just stops immediately at that point. It never goes to the Catch statement so I can handle it. That's what I'm really trying to address.