# .net webservice error

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, web-services, wcf-ria-services

I am making a program in silverlight with services.
Everything was working fine but when I started my program yesterday I got this error: CommunicationException was unhandled by user code, the remote server returned an error: NotFound
My code has worked before and I did not make any changes to it.
Any idea what this could be? And how to solve it.

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   bij System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bij System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   bij System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   bij System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)}

Stacktrace:
   bij System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   bij System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   bij System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   bij BiljartHandicap.UserValidationWebServiceReference.UserValidationWebServiceClient.UserValidationWebServiceClientChannel.EndValidateUsername(IAsyncResult result)
   bij BiljartHandicap.UserValidationWebServiceReference.UserValidationWebServiceClient.BiljartHandicap.UserValidationWebServiceReference.UserValidationWebService.EndValidateUsername(IAsyncResult result)
   bij BiljartHandicap.UserValidationWebServiceReference.UserValidationWebServiceClient.OnEndValidateUsername(IAsyncResult result)
   bij System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: Plug the Ethernet cable back in :-)

Answer (score 1):

Excerpted from [a previous SO answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098515/silverlight-wcf-database-problem/2098605#2098605):

> 'NotFound' is a generic error message that could mean just about anything.
>   ...snip...
>   In any case, something i have found invaluable for tracking this sort of issue is the Service Trace Viewer tool from Microsoft. Read all about it [right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx), all it takes is some simple changes to your web.config to enable the logging.